# How to Toggle the Bool value in XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-menu

In my android app, I've defined a bool value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="booleanvalue">false</bool>
</resources>
```

I'm using it to show or hide a menu function in my menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_on"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/show_menu1"
    android:visible="@bool/booleanvalue"
    />
```

However is it possible to get the negative value of the Boolean in the menu.xml without changing the original value?

I want it because there is another menu item which gets hidden when this menu 1 is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't negate** it in the XML file, Neither on the resource file.

But when the action that should hide one menu and show the other is performed, you can programmatically take care of that using `getVisibility()` and/or `setVisibility()` methods.

Example of a visibility toggle mechanism:

```
if(menu1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) menu1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else menu1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

if(menu2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) menu2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else menu2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` or `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your activity and set `menuItem.setVisible(true/false)`

Comment: Is it possible to do so in the XML?

Comment: xmls are immutable. You will have to implement some kind of code in your activity to trigger this. Also "I want it because there is another menu item which gets hidden when this menu 1 is displayed."

With this code your `menu1` will always be invisible.

Comment: Menu1 and Menu2 are opposites of each other. When 1 is shown, 2 is hidden and vice versa.

Comment: You will have to program that logic in your activity.